# How do I test a new app that has not been published against the shipping api?

Tags: shopify

I have been given access to the new shipping api, when creating an app in partner section and subsequent editing of it details I can set it as a shipping app.

I can then add a shipping rate provider in the test shop (same partner account) but can only see USPS, Canada post, Fedex etc..and can not see the app.  I imagine this is because the test app has not been published. But I do not want to publish the test app, and a requirement to publish an app before it can be added as a shipping provider would sort of hinder developement and testing ;-)

I have tried visiting http://your-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/auth?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY
but I can't see how that will add my test app as a shipping rate provider in the shipping preferences of the test app.

In fact I gave up on using http://your-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/auth?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY and moved over to user Oauth2 (I couldn't seem to get legacy auth examples working.)

I can register the app via OAuth2 however the option for this shipping app does not appear in the "Carrier calculated shipping rates"

Now I am really stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Edwards answer is correct as far as registering an app is concerned.

However if the app provides the shipping api it will "NOT" appear in carrier-calculated shipping rates config for shipping.

After you succesfully register the app you then have to make a POST call to carrier_services.json. e.g. in python

```
response = connection.post("%s/carrier_services.json" % shopify_session.site,headers)
```

Once you do this the new shipping api will be called during the checkout process.

Also note at the moment if you make any changes to the shipping configuration in preferences you will need make another POST to carrier_services.json to re-enable the shipping api.  It seems any changes to the shipping details currently unhooks the app from being called.

This is early days and no doubt things will change.

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure that the app you created has checked the “this is a shipping app” box.
2. Visit http://YOUR-STORE.myshopify.com/admin/api/auth?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY
3. Visit https://YOUR-STORE.myshopify.com/admin/shipping and the shipping service your app exposes should be available as a carrier-calculated shipping rate. (Hit that button at the top of the page if you haven’t added any yet.)

Comment: How will that allow me to add the app as a shipping rate provider in the shipping preferences of the test shop ?  I am new to shopify so haven't quite got me head around some of this workflow.

Comment: Thanks edward I didn't really understand the registration process.  I am trying the usps_app demo code for the shipping api running on heroku and can't seem to get the finalize method to work.  So I am going to deconstruct this and build my own version in appengine so I can actually understand what is going on.  I am only new to ruby and some of its syntax is making my eyes hurt ;-)

Comment: I moved over to using OAuth rather than legacy based app registration.  As I said in the modified original question, I can now register the shipping app but but it doesn't appear in the "Carrier calculated shipping rates" so have a road block.